# Log4Net - How to get the message property of an exception

Tags: log4net

Using Sitecore 10.2

I'm trying to log only my application logs into the database. The following approach works, but for the Columns `Logger` & `Message`, I would like to change the values.

**Sitecore.config**

```
<root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="DbLogAppender"/>
      </root>
      <appender name="DbLogAppender" type="Stratum.Foundation.Logging.Models.DbLogAppender, Stratum.Foundation.Logging">
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <connectionStringName value="logs"/>
        <param name="CommandText" value="usp_InsertLogFromApp" />
        <param name="CommandType" value="StoredProcedure" />            
        
        <parameter>
          <parameterName value="@logger" />
          <dbType value="String" />
          <size value="255" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%c" />
          </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <parameterName value="@message" />
          <dbType value="String" />
          <size value="4000" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%m" />
          </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <parameterName value="@exception" />
          <dbType value="String" />
          <size value="4000" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />          
        </parameter>
      </appender>
```

**DbLogAppender.cs**

```
public class DbLogAppender : ADONetAppender
{
   protected override void Append(LoggingEvent theEvent)
        {
            var eventData = theEvent.GetLoggingEventData();
            
            if (eventData.Message.Equals("My_Log", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                base.Append(theEvent);
            }
        }
}
```

This is how I'm logging the exception.

**BannersController.cs**

```
namespace Stratum.Feature.PageContent.Controllers
{
   public class BannersController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult RenderHeroBanner()
        {
            try
            {
                Convert.ToInt32("asd");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("My_Log", ex, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the database, the record is created like this:

| Logger | Message | Exception |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stratum.Feature.PageContent.Controllers.BannersController | My_Log | Exception: System.FormatException Message: Input string was not in a correct format. ....... |

In the `Logger` column, I would like to have the the method name also.
Current:  `Stratum.Feature.PageContent.Controllers.BannersController`
Expected: `Stratum.Feature.PageContent.Controllers.BannersController.RenderHeroBanner`

In the `Message` column, I would like to have the "Message" of the "Exception".
Current:  `My_Log`
Expected:  `Input string was not in a correct format`

In `Sitecore.config`, I have tried multiple `conversionPatterns` to achieve these, like `%method`, `%stracktrace`, `%stracktracedetails`, `%location`.  But they return empty values.

For what I'm expecting, is it possible OOB or do I need to extend any code. If so, please let me know the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a decorator `w/ ILog` Dependency and create a method something like and use that method in your client code

```
 public void Error(string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
 {
     _Log.Error($"[{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFilePath)}.{memberName}:{lineNumber}] - {message}");
 }
```

Comment: Sorry this was unclear. Could you please provide more explanation like where this new method should be created. Is it in my DbLogAppender.cs. If yes, then where should it be called.

Comment: Also, I had 2 questions. Does this answer include solution for both.